# Problemas com ObjectStateManager ao atualizar uma Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, poco

Estou com problemas para atualizar uma model, o código abaixo esta funcionando corretamente quando eu dou GET em uma model do contexto edito na tela (View) e dou um submit tudo ok mas quando eu tenho uma grid de dados onde eu carrego varias mensagens e por exemplo vou checkar (checkbox) nesta grid para alterar  um flag de ativo para inativo ele não procede mas também não da erro ?

Eu acho que tem a ver com o ObjectStateManager em todas as acoes que ele executa corretamente o State esta com Datached mas quando a não atualiza sem dar nenhum erro o State esta como Unchanged.

Uma otima observação a quem possa me ajudar é que este método sempre vira com o ID da minha Model ele so é usado para Editar e para inserir tenho outro método.

Segue o método

```js
       public void Edit(TEntity entity)
        {
            var entry = _context.Entry<TEntity>(entity);
            var pkey = _dbSet.Create().GetType().GetProperty("ID").GetValue(entity);

            if ((entry.State == EntityState.Detached))
            {
                var set = _context.Set<TEntity>();
                TEntity attachedEntity = set.Find(pkey);

                if (attachedEntity != null)
                {
                    var attachedEntry = _context.Entry(attachedEntity);
                    attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
                }
                else
                {
                    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }

            try
            {
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var failure in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0} Falha da validação ", failure.Entry.Entity.GetType());
                    foreach (var error in failure.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        sb.AppendFormat("- {0} : {1}", error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
                        sb.AppendLine();
                    }
                }

                throw new System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException("Erros da validação da Entidade: " + sb.ToString(), ex);
            }
        }
```

Quem puder me dar uma saída para que sempre este método de um UPDATE independente se de com vim o State, fico grato. ha e mais uma coisa andei mexendo e teve situações em que ele dava erro de ObjectStateManager existente também.

Comment: O problema está acredito que no View para o ViewModel... Voce utiliza WPF? MVVM?

Comment: Sim é uma aplicação MVC5 MVVM, estranho isso eu vou tentar aplicar o Automapper pois no caso que nao esta atualizando, eu fiz uma ModelView para adquar o que eu precisava na View coisas de tela entende com grid tals quando eu dou um form submit nao atuaaliza e nao da erro rrsrs vou integrar o Automapper fazer minha MV conversar corretamente com Mode DTO, breve posto aqui o que é ainda nao descobri.